# Como modelar um conjunto de 1 a 4 valores predeterminados

Tags: mysql, sql, modelagem

Estou modelando uma base MySQL onde as entidades principais são documentos. Entre vários outros campos, esses documentos se relacionam a uma ou mais *fases* de um determinado projeto.

São 4 valores básicos (vamos chamá-los A, B, C e D), e o valor da propriedade *fase* é um conjunto de 1 a 4 deles. Por exemplo, um documento pode estar relacionado apenas à fase A, às fases A e B, às fases B, C e D, etc.

Vejo várias maneiras de modelar isso, mas estou em dúvida sobre qual seria a mais adequada. As opções que considerei:

- 4 colunas "booleanas" (`TINYINT(1)`), uma para cada fase.
- Uma única coluna binária, com 4 bits (`BIT(4)`).
- Uma coluna do tipo *set*: `SET('A','B','C','D')`.
- Tabela de relacionamento.

Vou precisar obter/exibir tanto a lista de fases de um dado documento, quanto a lista de documentos ligados a determinada fase.

Qual seria a estrutura mais adequada neste caso? Quais critérios devo levar em conta para tomar essa decisão?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A menos que você esteja enfrentando problemas de desempenho, eu iria com a tabela de relacionamento, pois do contrário iria complicar um bocado suas *queries*. No entanto, se o número de documentos for muito grande em relação às fases, há uma alternativa menos custosa que ainda preserva a normalização dos dados:

Já que o número de conjuntos possíveis é pequeno (16 no máximo), você pode criar uma tabela separada para representar um conjunto. Essa tabela de conjuntos teria basicamente um ID - talvez codificado nesse padrão binário, mas não necessariamente - e mais nada. Então você criaria uma tabela de relacionamento entre cada conjunto e suas fases (1 + 4 + 6 + 4 + 1 = 16 linhas).

Já o documento, esse teria um campo que funcionaria como chave estrangeira pra tabela de conjuntos. Um inteiro de 4 bits é o bastante. Assim cada documento teria um dado ocupando o mínimo de espaço possível, o *overhead* estaria todo na tabela de conjuntos (+ um *join* adicional, é claro).

```
create table fase(
  id    serial primary key,
  nome  text
);

create table conjunto(
  id   tinyint(4) primary key
);

create table fase_conjunto(
  id_fase integer,
  id_conj tinyint(4)
);

create table documento(
  id    serial primary key,
  nome  text,
  fases tinyint(4)
);
```

Para obter todas as fases de um dado documento:

```
select f.*
from documento d
  join conjunto c on d.fases = c.id
  join fase_conjunto fc on fc.id_conj = c.id
  join fase f on fc.id_fase = f.id
where d.nome = "d2f12";
```

E todos os documentos de uma determinada fase:

```
select d.*
from fase f
  join fase_conjunto fc on fc.id_fase = f.id
  join conjunto c on fc.id_conj = c.id
  join documento d on d.fases = c.id
where f.nome = "Fase 1";
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6814f/2/0)

Comment: Pensando aqui: se você não fizer questão das *foreign keys*, a tabela `conjunto` é desnecessária. Só não sei se é uma boa ideia, afinal são apenas 16 linhas... De todo modo, dá pra economizar um join, comparando `fc.id_conj` diretamente com `d.fases`.

Comment: Interessante a ideia, mas realmente não tenho tantos documentos para justificar a complexidade. Na verdade duvido que performance seja um problema com qualquer uma das alternativas que coloquei na pergunta. Por isso fiquei meio sem parâmetro para escolher uma delas. Gostei do argumento pró-tabela de relacionamento, para preservar a normalização. As outras opções me parecem mais econômicas (não exigem tabela adicional), mas tirando o SET (que acho que só existe no MySQL), são meio feias e pouco auto-explicativas.

Comment: É, meu principal parâmetro aqui nem foi a eficiência, mas simplificar as *queries*. Minha experiência com BDs em geral é limitada, e imagino que as outras opções complicariam um pouco as consultas. Mas posso estar enganado. Vamos ver se alguém com mais domínio dessa área responde. P.S. Migrar de uma coluna binária (opção 2) para um esquema como este daqui não seria difícil, e vice-versa, de modo que há uma certa flexibilidade caso se venha a descobrir no futuro não ter tomado a decisão certa.

Comment: Eu acho que no fundo quero saber qual opção é mais "elegante". Será que a minha pergunta é baseada em opinião?

Comment: Sei lá... pra mim, "elegante" no contexto de um BD relacional vai sempre significar "normalizado", de modo que eu rejeitaria a coluna binária e talvez o que usa `set` (não tenho experiência, mas uma coluna `set` não violaria a 1ª forma normal?). Quanto às demais, minha preferência pela tabela de relacionamento é pelo fato que ela "homogeniza" as *queries* - enquanto as colunas booleanas exigiriam uma query diferente pra fase A, outra pra fase B, etc (i.e. cada query complexa envolvendo uma fase teria de ser ajustada para cada coluna booleana, não dá pra usar uma só query parametrizada).

Comment: Eu precisaria estudar mais, mas pela pesquisa rápida que fiz há controvérsias quanto a conjuntos violarem ou não a 1NF. Enfim, acho que você tem razão, em termos de elegância a tabela de relacionamento é padrão, e é sempre uma opção segura.