# Como criar um campo em uma tabela com valores pre cadastrados?

Tags: mysql

Preciso cadastrar em uma tabela 'PROJECTS' os seguintes campos :
nome, data_inicio, data_termino, valor, participantes e risco.
O campo risco tem que ser inteiro com as seguintes restriçoes :
0 - baixo, 1- medio, 2- alto. como fazer?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como modelar um conjunto de 1 a 4 valores predeterminados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99322/como-modelar-um-conjunto-de-1-a-4-valores-predeterminados)

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

O mysql suporta apenas que, campos do tipo "enum" sejam string. Então, para o campo `risco` ter estes valores 0,1,2 precisariam ser string. Não há uma forma de guardar no banco e ser tratado no banco de dados de forma "simples" sem a criação de procedures.

Você pode, inclusive, trabalhar com "baixo", "medio" e "alto" o que fica, inclusive, mais intuitivo no uso.

Tendo estas informações em código, você faz os tratamentos necessários.

Exemplo de tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `default_table` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_inicio` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_termino` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `participantes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `risco` enum('baixo','medio','alto') DEFAULT 'baixo',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Pois é.. também pensei em fazer dessa forma que você comentou. O lance é que, colocaram uma obrigatoriedade justo nesse campo, dizendo que teria que seguir essa regra de negócio. Acha possível cadastrar o campo na tabela como int e criar um vetor do mesmo tipo ou alguma função que atribua pelo menos as posições                [{ 0:'baixo', 1:'medio', 2:'alto' }]?